# Аналог функции fadeIn() или fadeOut в jQuery на чистом javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript, анимация

Задался вопросом написать функцию, подобную той, что есть в jQuery. Но что-то пока не очень получается. Что не так в этом коде?

```
window.onload = function () {

    function fadeIn() {
        var element = arguments[0];
        var delay = arguments[1];

        function alterElement() {
            var elementHeight = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).height;
            elementHeight = parseInt(elementHeight);
            elementHeight -= 10;
            element.style.height = elementHeight + 'px';
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) setInterval(alterElement, delay);
    }

    var block = document.getElementById('block');
    fadeIn(block, 500);
}
```

Вот кусок кода из исходника jQuery с единственным упоминанием слова fadeOut:

```
    // Generate shortcuts for custom animations
jQuery.each({
    slideDown: genFx( "show", 1 ),
    slideUp: genFx( "hide", 1 ),
    slideToggle: genFx( "toggle", 1 ),
    fadeIn: { opacity: "show" },
    fadeOut: { opacity: "hide" },
    fadeToggle: { opacity: "toggle" }
}, function( name, props ) {
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( speed, easing, callback ) {
        return this.animate( props, speed, easing, callback );
    };
});
```

Лично мне этот кусок ни о чем не говорит, а вам?

Comment: А вы посмотрите реализацию этих функций в самой jQuery. Правда, там копаться вроде не очень удобно в ней.

Comment: Есть два вида файла jQuery - один компактный( для тех, кому все равно, что внутри ) и удобочитаемый( для тех, кому не все равно, что внутри )

Comment: @Asen, я знаю, но во втором вроде тоже не очень удобно. Хотя реализацию функции, думаю, найти легко.

Comment: Я неправильно назвал функцию. Надо было fadeOut(). fadeIn это плавное появление.

Comment: @Construct, в `jQury` функция `fadeOut` написан через нефигового размера функцию `animate`

Comment: Этот кусок говорит нам, что есть `animate`, который плавно меняет любое свойство CSS. И словарь методов (`fadeIn`, `fadeOut` и т.д.) с указанием какие методы менять в той или иной анимации.

Смотрите на реализацию `animate`.

Comment: @Spectre, ну вот и я про то, что там многое связано и надо всё прочесть)

Comment: Хорошо. Мне не нужно крутой функции как в jQuery. Просто скажите, что не так в этом коде. Мне кажется реализация не совсем правильная, так как анимация бывает то рывками, то слишком быстрая (в зависимости от того, какие цифры я ставлю в цикле for и в интервале уменьшения высоты элемента)